# To show a set in open in subspace topology but not in order topology

Tags: general-topology

Let Y be the subset [0,1]$\cup ${2} of $R$. 
Show that the set {2} is open in subspace topology on Y but not open in order topology on Y.

A set in open in subspace topology on Y if we can write open set in Y = Y$\cap$ open set in $R$
So {2}= Y $\cap$ ($\frac{3}{2},\frac{5}{2}$)

How should I show that {2} is not open in order topology on Y?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the order topology on $[0,1]\cup\{2\}$, $\{2\}$ **is** an open subset.

I suspect you intended to ask whether $\{2\}$ is an open subset in the order topology on $[0,1)\cup\{2\}$. It isn't since this set is order-isomorphic to $[0,1]$.

Comment: I want to show that {2} is not open in order topology on Y=[0,1]$\cap$ {2}. Then how can you say {2} is an open subset?

Comment: The set $\{2\}$ is open in $Y$ in the order topology since it is $\{x\in Y:x>1\}$ and sets of the form $\{x\in Y:x>a\}$ are open by definition in the order topology.

Comment: How did you take a=1?

Answer (score 2):

In $A = [0,1) \cup \{2\}$ the set $\{2\}$ is not open in the order topology on $A$ in the inherited order, but it *is* open in the subspace topology, as you already noted.

The order topology on $A$ has as subbasic elements all sets of the form $(\leftarrow, a) = \{x \in a : x < a\}$ and $(a, \rightarrow) = \{x \in A: x > a\}$, (where $a \in A$(!!)). If $\{2\}$ were open, $2$ would have to be an internal point of $\{2\}$ and as $2 = \max(A)$ , $2$ is only contained in subbasic sets of the form $(a, \rightarrow)$, where $a \in A$(and $a <2$ or the set is empty), and as the family of such sets is  closed under finite intersections, such sets form a local base for $2$. But no $(a, \rightarrow) = \{2\}$, as $a \in A, a< 2$, so $a < 1$ and any point $b \in (a,1)$ would be in $(a, \rightarrow)$ but not in $\{2\}$.

In $B = [0,1] \cup \{2\}$ we could use $(1, \rightarrow) = \{2\}$ to see the singleton set is closed in that case, as $1 \in B$ now.